# how to get loaded kernel module file position

Tags: linux, module, command, kernel

command :

```
 lsmod 

 loaded kernel module list
```

command :

```
 modinfo `lsmod | awk {'print $1'}` | awk {'print $2'}

 loaded kernel module file position
```

I want list
KernelModule | file position

ex :

```
xfs | /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64/kernel/fs/xfs/xfs.ko
```

how to get example list Command?

Comment: Too many ways for achive required output. With bash, awk, sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lsmod | grep -v ^Module | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 -I MOD sh -c "echo -n MOD; echo -n ' | '; modinfo MOD | grep filename | awk '{print \$2}'"
```

Comment: if you like it, please mark an answer as correct :)